# Is it possible to debug a Java program running in jni4net?

Tags: java, c#, iis-express, jni4net

I'm currently using a Java library via [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/) in a C# application running on IIS Express, and the Java library is throwing an exception. Is it possible to attach a debugger to debug the Java code?

**Attempt:**
I tried to add the following to the JVM options as per the instructions provided by [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html):

```
setup.AddJVMOption("-agentlib", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005");
```

but get an exception:

```
Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the AddJVMOption-String to:
`setup.AddJVMOption("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044");`

I am able to connect to the jni4net part via Eclipse, maybe you should just omit the first argument `("-agentlib", ...)`

When I use `setup.AddJVMOption("-agentlib", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005");`

I get an Exception in CreateJVM