# Is it possible to debug a C#/.Net program running via jni4net?

Tags: java, c#, jni4net

I'm making an method call from Java to a C#-DLL via jni4net and I want to debug the C#-Code.

I tried the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951124/visual-studio-auto-attach-to-a-process-when-the-process-is-spawned/4042545#4042545), but it didn't work for me. What else can I do?

Comment: You could try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308402/is-it-possible-to-debug-a-java-program-running-in-jni4net

Comment: Thx @Phate01, but my method call is in the other direction: Java to .Net